# Angular Universal - Pre-render only for web crawlers?

Tags: server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am intending to user Angular Universal for server side rendering (SSR) but this should only be done for crawlers and bots from selected search engines.

What I want is the following schema:

[image]

source: https://dingyuliang.me/use-prerender-improve-angularjs-seo/

After following [the official instructions](https://angular.io/guide/universal) to set up SSR I can now validate that Googlebot (finally) "sees" my website and should be able to index it.

However, at the moment *all* requests are rendered on the server. Is there a way to determine whether incoming requests are coming from search engines and pre-render the site only for them?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with Nginx.

In Nginx you can forward the request to the universal served angular application via..

```
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|yahoo|bingbot") {
            proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:5000; 
            break;
        }
        root /var/www/html;
```

..assuming that you are serving angular universal `via 127.0.0.1:5000`.

In case a browser user agent comes along, we serve the page via `root /var/www/html`

So the complete config would be something like..

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name angular.local;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|yahoo|bingbot") {
            proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:5000; 
            break;
        }

        root /var/www/html;
    }

}
```

Comment: few more bots `linkedinbot|googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|developers\.google\.com`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with IIS:

1. Add the Angular Universal to your project according to the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/universal)
2. In order to get rid of complex folder structures, change the following line in `server.ts`

   ```
   const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/<Your Project>/browser');
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   const distFolder = process.cwd();
   ```
3. Run the `npm run build:ssr` command. You will end up with the `browser` and `server` folders inside the `dist` folder.
4. Create a folder for hosting in IIS and copy the files that are in the `browser` and `server` folders in to the created folder.

   ```
   iis\
     -assets\
     -favicon.ico
     -index.html
     -main.js => this is the server file
     -main-es2015.[...].js
     -polyfills-es2015.[...].js
     -runtime-es2015.[...].js
     -scripts.[...].js
     -...
   ```
5. Add a new file to this folder named `web.config` with this content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
         <rules>
           <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url=".*" />
             <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
               <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(.*[Gg]ooglebot.*)|(.*[Bb]ingbot.*)" negate="true" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
           </rule>
           <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url=".*" />
             <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(.*[Gg]ooglebot.*)|(.*[Bb]ingbot.*)" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:4000/{R:0}" />
           </rule>
         </rules>
       </rewrite>
       <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
6. Inside this folder open a Command Prompt or PowerShell and run the following:

   ```
   > node main.js
   ```

   Now you should be able to view your Server-Side Rendered website with `localhost:4000` (if you haven't changed the port)
7. Install the IIS Rewrite Module
8. Add the folder to your IIS for hosting

IIS will redirect requests that have `googlebot` or `bingbot` in them to `localhost:4000` which is handled by Express and will return server-side rendered content.

You can test this with Google Chrome, open Developer Console, from the menu select "More tools>Network conditions". Then from the User Agent section disable "Select automatically" and choose Googlebot.

Answer (score 0):

Just managed what you wanted but did not find any anwser providing a detailed step by step with Angular Universal and Express server.
So I post here my solution, any idea of improvement welcomed !

First add this function to the server.ts

```
function isBot(req: any): boolean {
  let botDetected = false;
  const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'];
  if (userAgent) {
    if (userAgent.includes("Googlebot") ||
      userAgent.includes("Bingbot") ||
      userAgent.includes("WhatsApp") ||
      userAgent.includes("facebook") ||
      userAgent.includes("Twitterbot")
    ) {
      console.log('bot detected with includes ' + userAgent);
      return true;
    }
    const crawlers = require('crawler-user-agents');
    crawlers.every(entry => {
      if (RegExp(entry.pattern).test(userAgent)) {
        console.log('bot detected with crawler-user-agents ' + userAgent);
        botDetected = true;
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    })
    if (!botDetected) console.log('bot NOT detected ' + userAgent);
    return botDetected;
  } else {
    console.log('No user agent in request');
    return true;
  }
}
```

this function uses 2 modes to detect crawlers (and asumes that the absence of user-agent means that the request is from a bot), the first is a 'simple' manual detection of a string within the header's user-agent and secondly a more advanced detection based on the package 'crawler-user-agents' that you can install to your Angular project like this :

```
npm install --save crawler-user-agents
```

Second, once this function added to your server.ts, just use it in each

```
server.get(`/whatever`,  (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
}
```

of your Express server export function, for which the 'whatever' route should have a different behaviour based on Bot detection.

Your 'server.get()' functions become :

```
server.get(`/whatever`,  (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  if (!isBot(req)) {
   // here if bot is not detected we just return the index.hmtl for CSR
    res.sendFile(join(distFolder + '/index.html'));
    return;
  }
   // otherwise we prerend
  res.render(indexHtml, {
    req, providers: [
      { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req }
    ]
  });
});
```

To further improve the server load for SEO when a bot is requesting a page I also implemented 'node-cache' because in my case SEO bots do not need the very lastest version of each page, for this I found a good answer here :
[#61939272](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939272/how-to-configure-cache-in-angular-universal)