# How to configure cache in Angular Universal

Tags: node.js, angular, caching, angular-universal

I followed a tutorial for integrating Universal in our Angular 9 app.
Now we have server.ts configured.

In every tutorial I see this:

```
// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
```

and then:

```
server.get(
        '*.*',
        express.static(distFolder, {
            maxAge: '1y',
        })
    );
```

If we leave it like that I suppose every request is cached, also what goes to /api. Is this right?
Our app has lots of "product pages" where stock and price could change frequently. So we need to have always fresh stock and price. For this reason I wouldn't cache data from server that is returned from our API calls that are in "/api/" path (or https://api.my-app.com" if absolute path is needed). Leaving everything like written above should cache everything, if I'm not wrong. I made a test changing a price directly in the database and I expected to see the old one, but it's not like that, I see always the fresh one. 
So my doubt is that cache mechanism dosn't work. And also when I navigate through components I continue to see every api calls (not cached)

Can anybody explain me better this mechanism please?

Another question about this is: If cache works, how to clear it in node? Node caches in memory everything. I supposed cache would be cleared when we stop node. Is this right?

This is my package json:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",
    "start": "npm run ng -- serve",
    "serve:server": "node ./dist-server/main.js",
    "serve:server:debug": "node --inspect ./dist-server/main.js",
    "start:server": "npm run build:server && node ./dist-server/main.js",
    "start:server:debug": "npm run build:server && node ./dist-server/main.js --inspect",
    "build": "npm run ng -- build",
    "build:server": "ng run my-app:server:production",
    "ssr:watch": "ng run my-app:serve-ssr:production",
    "demo:ssr:watch": "ng run universal-demo:serve-ssr:dev",
    "build-all": "npm-run-all build-production build:server-app:prod",
    "start:express-server": "ts-node -P ./src/tsconfig.server.json ./server.ts",
    "prerender": "ts-node -P ./server.tsconfig.json ./prerender.ts",
    "prerender:debug": "ts-node -P ./server.tsconfig.json --inspect ./prerender.ts",
    "test": "npm run ng -- test",
    "lint": "npm run ng -- lint",
    "e2e": "npm run ng -- e2e",
    "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
    "compodoc": "npx compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json",
    "build:stats": "ng build --stats-json --prod",
    "build-preprod": "ng build --configuration preprod --index=/src/index/preprod/index.html",
    "build-production": "ng build --configuration production --index=/src/index/production/index.html",
    "build-staging": "ng build --configuration staging --index=/src/index/staging/index.html"
  }
```

This is my angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["src/assets/sass"]
            },
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
              "src/main-sw.js",
              "src/assets/js/intersection-observer.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss",
              "src/styles/my-app.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "staging": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "src/app/config/ngsw-config.json",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true
            },
            "preprod": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "src/app/config/ngsw-config.json",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.preprod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "src/app/config/ngsw-config.json",
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["src/assets/sass"]
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build",
            "serverTarget": "my-app:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "my-app:server:production",
            "routes": ["/"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my-app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-app"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your `angular.json` file? Do you use a reverse proxy before the request hit nodejs, like nginx?

Comment: I added angular json. I deploy dist and dist-server in the root of my site that is under IIS. In IIS I have a rule that proxy everything to node on port 4200. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I think you got confused with cache.  The example you showed is to configure HTTP cache browser side, which you can do from either `server.ts`, or IIS. If your API calls are not going through `server.ts`, you need to do it from IIS. Nothing will be cached in nodejs emory or anything

Answer (score 7):

The following code applies to static files which are located in the `dist/browser` directory after building the project. These are mostly JavaScript, CSS and image files. The `maxAge` will set the Cache-Control header which indicates the maximum amount of time the file will be considered fresh. Again, this **only** applies to serving the files in `dist/browser` which will **never** change.

```js
server.get(
  '*.*',
  express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y',
  })
);
```

---

The following code is included just as an example of how additional endpoints can be added to the Express server: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html. It does not have anything to do with caching.

```
// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
```

---

The following code is what renders the HTML response using the Angular app. There is **no** caching provided for this in the default implementation because it would differ depending on how frequently content changes in your app.

```js
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(
    indexHtml, 
    { 
      req, 
      providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] 
    });
});
```

Here's some pseudocode of how caching could be implemented. The `cache` variable could be an in-memory cache like [Redis](https://redis.io/) or some other implementation.

```js
server.get('*',
  // Middleware to check if cached response exists
  (req, res, next) => {
    const cachedHtml = cache.get(req.url);
    if (cachedHtml) {
      // Cache exists. Send it.
      res.send(cachedHtml);
    } else {
      // Cache does not exist. Render a response using the Angular app
      next();
    }
  },
  // Angular SSR rendering
  (req, res) => {
    res.render(
      indexHtml,
      {
        req,
        providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }]
      },
      (err: Error, html: string) => {
        // Cache the rendered `html` for this request url to use for subsequent requests
        cache.set(req.url, html);

        res.send(html);
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. No browser folder is created after build. Maybe I'm missing something during build process. I edited my originale post adding scripts part of my package json configuration. What I do for production build is:
1. ng build --configuration production --index=/src/index/production/index.html (in order to have a production build created in "dist" folder)
2. ng run my-app:server:production (output main.js file is created in "dist-server" build)
3. Transfer dist and dist folder to root of site and start node with node dist-server/main.js
Is this correct?

Comment: What you have can work. It's just configured differently than the default setup. The `dist/browser` folder I was referring to is the `dist` folder in your case.