# HTML template engine with both ASP.net core and JS support

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, html-templates

Is there any HTML templating engine, which can be ran with ASP.net core at the server side and with JS on the client side/browser, and produce same HTML output with a level of consistency?

The benefit will be to have the flexibility in rendering, either in the client side or in the server side.

Comment: If I understood correctly you are looking for server-side rendering of a SPA that would be served by the ASP.NET Core pipelines, right?

Comment: @Sasan yes that can be said.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: I needed a mechanism to add SSR to my Angular app only for web crawlers like Google and Bing bot. I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895461/angular-universal-pre-render-only-for-web-crawlers) if that's something that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I've found the `Liquid` templating engine to be available both in .net and JS. It is available across many more languages and frameworks.

The .net library is- https://github.com/sebastienros/fluid
The JS library is- https://liquidjs.com/

The "Orchard core" project by Microsoft is also using the "Fluid" library. And there is also "Scriban" .net library with liquid support.

I've not tested them yet in a project. So, no concrete idea at that front. Hope this may help someone.